Some game with a Boolean function
Let $f: \{0,1\}^{m + k} \to \{0,1\}^n$ be some function,
where $m = n \log n$  and $k < \log \log \log \log n$.
Consider the following game between Alice and Bob that determinates by $f$, $c_A$ (Alice's capital), $c_B$ (Bob's capital)
and some $b \in \{0,1\}^n$.
Consider Boolean variables $x_1, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_k$.
Initially all this variables are equal to zeros. The  players can change the value of  a variable from zero to one by using their money. The cost of each such change is equal to $1$.
Bob can change any variable and Alice can change only $x_1, \ldots, x_m$.
The goal of Bob is to make $f(x_1, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_k) = b$ and the  Alice's goal is the opposite.
A player makes his or her move iff the current value of $f$ does not correspond to his or her goal.
A player looses if he or she spends all his or her money and the current value of $f$ does not correspond to his or her goal.
Let $c_A:= \frac{m}{4}$ and $c_B:=\frac{m}{400}$.
Question Is it true that for every $f$ Alice has a winning strategy for all $b \in \{ 0,1\}^n$ except at most $\frac{2^n}{n}$ values (for large enough $n$)?
Consider the case $k=0$. In this case Alice has a winning strategy for all $b$ except at most $1$ value even if $c_A = c_B$. Indeed, the players have equal opportunities and hence Bob cannot has winning strategy for different $b_1$ and $b_2$ (because Alice also can use one of them).
So, my question is if $k$ is some tiny function, can it dramatically change the situation?
The similar games were considered in 1 2. My question is also related to some problem in Kolmogorov complexity.
Reposted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54685/some-game-on-a-boolean-function.

This is quite obscure. Do you mean Bob must and can only play when the value isn't $b$ and Alice must and can only play when it is $b$? And the game only ends when either Bob or Alice have no money left? I suppose $m$ is a multiple of $400$ or the game would get stuck. Do the players know all $f$ before the game starts, or do they only find out its value after every change?

@ClaudeChaunier Both players know $f$. Yes, both players make theirs moves if they do not like the current value of $f$. And they loose if the value is bad and they do not have money to change the value (or if it is impossible even with money).

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/54685/5038
